# Seeking boundaries of Canadian Location Code regions used for Meteorological Services?

Tags: shapefile, data, geometry, administrative-boundaries, canada

I have looked into the GADM datasets. The problem is that Canada has a very non-standardized level-2 Administrative Zone identification across the various Territories and Provinces. As a result, their Meteorological Weather Forecasting uses a unique system of boundaries they created. [Info on this here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forecast_region). Visually, you can [see these boundaries here](https://weather.gc.ca/warnings/index_e.html) on a map. I am looking for datasets to reproduce those regions (ideally shapefile format, but I'm open to other formats so long as I can generate/transform the geometries from it using something like QGIS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're well hidden! I found a directory with archives of shapefiles [here](http://dd.weather.gc.ca/meteocode/geodata/version_5.3.0/). There's some documentation [here](http://dd.weather.gc.ca/about_dd_apropos.txt). It looks like the polygons aren't updated regularly, but you can sign up to the mailing list to find out when they are, according to that document.

If you download [this archive](http://dd.weather.gc.ca/meteocode/geodata/version_5.3.0/MSC_GIS_Polygon_Pkg_V5_3_0_Land_Proj.zip) (33MB), the forecast zones are in land_CLCBaseZone_detail_proj.shp. (The *detail* files have accurate coast lines. The *coarse* files are more general.)

Comment: in Name field there are codes like BC082640 (that should be Fraser Valley) correct?

Comment: I can't thank you enough - I need to learn your Google-fu techniques. I'm thinking the PubStdZone_detail_proj.shp files should do the trick perfectly (found in the first link under "Land Projection" set). I was having some doubts about anyone coming through on this but you surprised me.

@Mapperz - For example: I see the Fields "NAME" & "NOM" with value "Windsor - Essex - Chatham-Kent" and also the Fields "PUBSTDZA" & "CLC_V5" with value  "041400" under the dataset I mentioned above

Comment: @BrandonK: actually, I just searched for "canada forecast weather region shp" and that document was the second hit. The really helpful thing is that Google knows that when I say, "shp," I really mean "Shapefile."